# React + Webpack SVG Icons Render Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm trying to render custom SVG icons that have been designed and exported for web. These are stored locally within an assets folder.

Using this package ["svg-inline-loader"](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader)

Here is how I'm using the icon:

```
import MainLogo from '../../../assets/svg/logos/mainlogo.svg';

<img src={MainLogo} alt="" />
```

Here is the snippet I have from my webpack config

```
//SVG Icon Loader
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      },
```

The render output I get the following:

[image]

The SVG icons do not render however, that path does not look right.

Is there a better way to do this or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the webpack server to serve your assets by copying your resources to public folder using [`Copy WebPack Plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)